# Unidentified user details in the sidebar after log in

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, sidebar, react-native-navigation, asyncstorage

I am using `AsyncStorage` for storing and retrieving the  user data. 
I am using `StackActions.reset` for login to go to my Home Screen but for some reasons the Sidebar doesn't retrieve anything from the `AsyncStorage`, it will just appear if I reload the `emulator(Ctrl R)`. I put the retrieve function in the `ComponentDidMount` of my `sidebar.js` *file* and it doesn't really go the after logging in .

Comment: Please can you add some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Async Storage is an async process.  So it might be that your componentDidMount is completing before the getAsync process to retrieve your user details is completed.  Although, if you added some code, it will help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: The problem is that when I navigate to Home screen it doesn't include the drawer because of my stacknavigator so I fixed it by recreating my navigation by following the Authentication flow of react-navigation and include drawer in some screens though I encounter new problem because the Initial route is mounting twice when I tried to navigate to the other screen.For example, I'm in the Log In screen then I press the sign up button the Sign up screen will appear fast then will go back again to the Log in screen and It will just work if i press the button again. Anyways, thank you for replying.